# lighting fire safety

Tags: safety, light, replacement, fire

Is it safe to use a soft 3 way 30/50/150 Watt incandescent bulb in a lamp that requires 23 CFL max light to prevent fire.
It is the only bulb that I could find but only the 150W setting works with this bulb in the lamp.
I want the bright light so am hoping this light will be safe to use. The volts are 120 for this light.

Comment: When you say “requires,” is that based on what was in it, or is there a label that says that is what the fixture/lamp is rated for? If it is rated for 23w CFL, then you’re exceeding that with a 150W incandescent.

Comment: Why do you want to put an incandescent in the fixture to begin with?

Answer (score 8):

No, that is not safe.  The 23W CFL limit means that you should not use a bulb that uses more than 23W of power.  A 30/50/150W 3-way will use more than that on its lowest setting.

If you don't want to use a CFL, and I don't blame you, please consider an LED bulb.  These generate even less heat than a CFL.  Use the ACTUAL power rating, which is likely to be in the 5-10W range rather than the "equivalent" power rating.

Comment: Actually, a 150-watt-equivalent bulb will probably be higher than 10 watts. Far example, at 17 watts: https://www.homedepot.com/p/SANSI-150-Watt-to-200-Watt-Equivalent-A19-Dimmable-LED-Light-Bulb-in-Warm-White-3000K-1-Pack-01-02-001-011730/313138179

Answer (score 4):

First, this is dangerous as discussed by everyone else. "convenience" is not an exception to

Second, a 50/100/150 incandescent will NOT give you 150W in that fixture.  It will only give 100W, because of the way the bulbs are internally wired.

However, there are "50/100/150" LED bulbs that are actually in the 23W neighborhood.  And even better, they do an internal trick so you get the maximum brightness "150" in a simpler fixture like yours.  *That's what you actually want*.

That said, these LED bulbs do cost some money, but you only have to buy them once.